# How to install setup.py at runtime

Tags: python, subprocess, setup.py

I have a c++ extension module(let's say test.so) for python.
I think the correct way to import it in my script is using:

```
python setup.py install
```

then run:

```
python myscript.py (in which import test is called)
```

However, I want to call my script in a python subprocess. So how can I combine these two commands in Popen? Is it possible to call install setup.py within myscript.py. 
Moreover, is it possible to call python setup.py install with test.so at non-current directory

Comment: Ask one question at a time, please. This sounds like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) anyway. If your C++ module requires compilation etc, there's a large number of things which could go wrong in `setup.py install` so it makes sense to decouple installation from execution. Package everything in compiled binary form for your target platform if you like.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `run()` instead of `Popen()`

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['python', 'setup.py', 'install'])
subprocess.run(['python', 'myscript.py'])
```

To open a file you can use `Popen()`

```
import subprocess
import sys
subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "<file-name with location>"]).communicate()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But how to install the module and call my script at the same time using subprocess.run()? Wouldn't the module be invisible for my script(which is run in the second subprocess) after the first subprocess being finished and killed?